# To block user after incorrect pwd for more than 3 times

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a arraylist and i want to store the user and store in session. and my aim is if a particular using login incorrect password for more than 3 times his a/c should be blocked.

```
ArrayList NoOfAttempts = (ArrayList)HttpContext.Current.Session["Attempts"];

                if (NoOfAttempts == null || (NoOfAttempts.Count > 0 && NoOfAttempts[0].ToString() != user))
                   NoOfAttempts = new ArrayList();

                    NoOfAttempts.Add(user);


                // Block User f it is more that 2 times -- NoOfAttempts[0].ToString()
                if (NoOfAttempts.Count>2)
                    UserService.DeactivateUser(user);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem a little more. Is something not working?

Comment: @thewisegod i want to handle if a user try incorrect pwd for more than 3 times his a/c should be blocked.In my case i can able to store only one value in session.